# Updating SMS Inbox when list has already been displayed as Message arrives

Tags: sms

I am creating an app in which I have to import the SMS inbox. My doubt is when the inbox list has already been displayed and I get an SMS during that time, how do i update my list and display the arrived SMS in the list? Thank you in advance

Comment: What platform are you working on?

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleCursorAdapter. Try this code:

```
public class InboxList extends ListActivity{

private ListAdapter adapter;

        private static final Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

        super.onCreate(bundle);

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, null, null, null);

        startManagingCursor(c);




    String[] columns = new String[] { "address","body"};



    int[] names = new int[] { android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2};

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.inboxlist, c, columns,names);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

  }
}
```